# How to extract some text from a web page and add it to my current web page using google blogspot?

Tags: css, blogs

Using code how can I add this text "Yes :)" to my blog.

In other words, how can I copy the text from [this page](http://amiconnectedtotheinternet.com/) and put it in the blog that I am designing. I don't want to put it in a frame, but just copy this text.

Comment: You won't be able to do this using CSS...

Comment: @HunterTurner does that have something to do with the page that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: You need PHP and/or Javascript to do that not CSS.

Comment: No. CSS does not function in this way. In order to retrieve data from another page you're going to have to use something like javascript.

Comment: What you're talking about is known as web scraping. If the page is in a different domain there will be issues with Javascript. You rather need a sever side programming language like Asp.Net, PHP, etc.